# post last messages YouTube comments function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I saw this new YouTube function from their video comments where it shows a link that says "2 messages have been posted since you arrived", so this basically uses an ajax request which keeps requesting the database since the date you arrived on the page but how can this be done since you must have the date of your arrival inside this ajax request which keeps on updating itself and changing your date of arrival to NOW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally used php session to store the date variable, this way the variable isnt affected when inserted in the ajax request wich constantly reloads itself(the variable keeps its unique value(the time the user arrived on the page) , you can also use a variable selected from a database.

Answer (score 0):

The internal `latest_time` variable is updated each time the `AJAX` request is sent.

The response is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <poll_delay>
  <![CDATA[15000]]>
 </poll_delay>
 <latest_time>
  <![CDATA[1289325319]]>
 </latest_time>
 <return_code>
  <![CDATA[0]]>
 </return_code>
 <comments>
  <![CDATA[]]>
 </comments>
</root>
```

, the `latest_time` is stored on the client side and used in the next request.

Comment: Why an XML, what XML have to do here?

Comment: @tada: it's youtube's `AJAX` response.

Comment: I am using right now the NOW variable but first inserting it in the database this keeps it from changing when in the AJAX constant reload function, i'm getting better result with this technique